# azure blob storage reader access not working as expected

Tags: azure-storage

I have assigned a Role Based Storage Reader access to an Azure user for an Azure Storage Account. The User is able to see the Storage account but unable to see any blobs or tables or queue. Why is that? I thought Reader access should allow a User to View what is inside a Blob service i.e containers and individual blobs?  I have attached a screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baaCa.png)

Changing the permission to 'Contributor' solves the problem but grants much more permission than required.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

RoleBasedAccess is for resource level and not for individual resource entities in storage service. If you need to provide ReadAccess, WriteAccess permissions on storage blobs/containers then you should refer to these msdn links 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/ 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/

Comment: What is the Point of Role Based Access than? Its level of Granularity is absolutely rubbish. Shared Access Signature are difficult to maintain. You pretty much need to develop another dot net application which Creates and Manages Shared Access Signatures. It is like developing another Authentication System. With Shared Access Signature you don't know which User accessed your resource. Anyone with a valid SAS can.